# Interbase to Firebird Migration

Tags: database, database-migration, interbase, firebird-3.0

Besides doing a data pump. Is there any other solutions for migrating?

Can you take a GBK and restore it to firebird? Is there any other migration issues you may have run into?

Comment: Your question is unfortunately too broad for stack overflow. You should really ask one specific question, not three, two of which are rather broad and open-ended. You may want to consider asking your questions on the firebird-support mailing list. See https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/mailing-lists/ for details.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Besides doing a data pump. Is there any other solutions for migrating?

no, this is the only solution

> 2. Can you take a GBK and restore it to firebird?

no, it is not compatibile backups files

> 3. Is there any other migration issues you may have run into?

you can run into many issues and as @Mark Rotteveel say it is to board. You can talk about specific issue you have.
I can point you to few issues:

- Ambiguous field name between tables - as Interbase allow you to do select from two tables with same field names and put this names in the where clause without aliasing it
- field not contained in the aggregate - as Interbase buggly check fields when you do group by
- order by in aggregate like `select count(*) from table_name ORDER BY some field` Interbase allow this Firebird not
- Count(*) return Int64 in Firebird in Interbase it is Integer
- identifiers longer then 31 chars are not allowed in current Firebird Interbase allows it but not handle it as it understand only first 31 chars
- if you use Delphi and IBX - you can not use Boolean fields in Firebird as IBX handling is not compatibile with Firebird